# How do I turn off "Automatically Switch to Debug Perspective" mode in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, debugging, perspective

Is there a way to turn off this mode?  I must have clicked it by accident, and now it's getting really annoying.

I've looked in the preferences and perspectives pane, but can't see anything.  Does anyone know where this option is configured?

Comment: I would really like to add +2.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Perspectives -> Open the associated perspective when application suspends

Comment: @sdolan: The search field in the preferences dialog is very useful for finding these things

Comment: Note that this doesn't work. Only real solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27507568/1599699

Comment: @Andrew you may have another problem. This works for me and probably others judging by the up votes.

Comment: Congrats. There are different versions.

Answer (score 6):

## 1

Other option is you can also `reset` your `perspective` `preference` from `windows` -> `reset perspective` and then `run/debug` then a `dialog` asking to switch to `debug perspective` when every time you debug the application and say check `NO`.

## 2

Goto `Windows` - > `preference` -> `General` ->`perspectives` -> make default your perspective or press `reset to default` to forget the previous settings.

Answer (score 0):

@skaffman
in addition to this you may also need to set the Prefrences> Run/Debug> Perspectives> "Open associated perspective when an application suspends" to Prompt or never.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window→perspective→close perspective.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to click on "Java" perspective icon in upper right corner, then under Window menu select Perspective, then Reset Perspective..., it will say "Reset the Java perspective to its default?", then click on "Reset Perspective".