# Disable Automatic Perspective Change in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I use Eclipse for coding, but I have a problem.  When I debug a C++ project, Eclipse automatic switches to the Debug perspective, but I don't want the automatic switch.  How can I disable the automatic switching?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I turn off "Automatically Switch to Debug Perspective" mode in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515762/how-do-i-turn-off-automatically-switch-to-debug-perspective-mode-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 43):

The accepted answer did not work for me debugging Java on Eclipse Juno SR1, but this did:

1. **Window | Preferences...** menu item
2. Choose **Run/Debug** on the left, about half-way down.
3. Choose **Perspectives** under that
4. Select **Never** at **Open the associated perspective when launching** and **Open the associated perspective when an application suspends**

Comment: Thank you!
This did work for me on Kepler, the accepted answer didnt.

Comment: Works for me with the Mars release

Comment: I was looking for enabling the automatic perspective change when starting debug in CDT. Choosing "Always" in both selection boxes worked. But when finishing debug it does not return to C/C++ perspective.