# How to Prevent Eclipse from Changing Perspectives

Tags: eclipse, weblogic11g

I've been using Eclipse with Weblogic with the integrated the WebLogic Server for about a year. Last week Eclipse "got confused" and I ended up having to reinstall it (long story). I've reconfigured most things back to the way I had them, but there is one setting I just can't work out...

Before I had to reinstall I created my own Eclipse perspective that had all of the windows I want and positioned where I want them. I used this to do all of my development. Now that I've reinstalled Eclipse I've recreated the perspective and this works well. However, when I start Weblogic in debug mode Eclipse insists on changing to the built-in Debug perspective.

How do I force Eclipse to either
1. Not change perspective  or
2. To change to my perspective

Either will do as I only intend to use my own perspective.

I know this is possible because I had it working this way before I reinstalled.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I turn off "Automatically Switch to Debug Perspective" mode in eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515762/how-do-i-turn-off-automatically-switch-to-debug-perspective-mode-in-eclipse)

Comment: @Steve Chambers, FYI, The question is the same but the solution given didn't work for me (see answer below). In the end I gave up and reinstalled Eclipse!

Comment: I have the same problem with the Weblogic plugin in Eclipse Kepler! Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi @electrotype - not exactly a solution, but in the end I gave up with all of Eclipse's 'little quirks' and moved to the community edition of InteliJ (because it's free)

Comment: @Stormcloud - Ok thanks. My solution, in the end, is to use the "debug" perspective as my main one and configure it like was my previous main perspective!

Answer (score 3):

Go to Window --> Preferences --> Run/Debug --> Perspective.

Here you will find a group of radio buttons grouped as "Open the associated perspective when launching".

Select "Prompt" or "Never" either to ask you every time or not to change the perspective when you run or debug application.

Comment: Hi Ras, it didn't quite work as I expected. It's still flipping to the Debug Perspective when WebLogic starts up (in debug mode) with out asking me. However, it's now asking me if I want to flip perspectives back to the correct perspective when the code hit's a break point.

Comment: You are facing such issue because you might have changed wrong radio button group. In the same configuration there are two groups of radio buttons: 1. "Open the associated perspective when launching". 2. "Open the associated perspective when an application suspends". Make sure that you are changing value of correct radio buttons group as written in my answer.

Comment: I've set both radio buttons to "prompt" and all of the dropdown boxes for all Application Types/Launchers to my Perspective. However it's still insisting on opening the debug Perspective.

Answer (score 1):

When eclipse asks for the first time to change to debug or some other perspective. it gives a dialog box with YES and NO.
So to solve your problem you have to do two things.
1. Check a  checkbox in same dialog box which states remember my decision and.
2. Click on No.

It will never ask you to change perspective to debug while debugging.

Comment: Hi Ankit, Thanks for replying. Eclipse isn't popping up a dialog box. I can only assume that I've accidentally told it that it *should* swap perspective with out asking. Any idea how I re-enable the dialog box?

Comment: Hi Stormcloud you can have a look at this link

Comment: Hi Stormcloud please look at the answer of RAS. its the answer that you want